# Sync vb.net application with a cloud?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dropbox, google-drive-api, onedrive

I am building application which I want to be synced to a cloud (skydrive, dropbox or google drive). Means it can upload freely to the cloud files to a cloud folder (for example, I want to upload doc.rtf to folder "my documents/example" at the cloud) and download from it by file name and path (in the cloud). Is it possible, and if it's possible - how can I do it? If I need a libary or a dll to do it, please write only free libary or dll.

Comment: Why not simply point to the local folder that is linked to eg. dropbox by the dropbox/drive/.. program?

Comment: Beacuse I cwant to connect by my program one account to many computers, that don't have my account connected to their computer with desktop versions of the clouds.

Comment: sounds a bit dangerous as you have to store you login data in your programme

Comment: Never mind; What I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

For dropbox I think the REST API should be the way to go >> [DropBox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs)

For Skydrive this might be useful >> [SkyDrive .Net API Client](http://skydriveapiclient.codeplex.com/)

Comment: the Dropbox API link is not available. Here is the new [link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation)